# Store Facebook Name in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, facebook

I need to store a users public facebook name in my MYSQL database, when they fill out a form in my canvas based application.

This is what I have, but for some reason the name never makes it into the database - everything else does..

```
$submit = $_POST['submit'];

if(isset($_POST['submit']) )
{
//form data
$name = $me['name'];
$q1 = $_POST['bromance'];
$q2 = $_POST['couple'];
$q3 = $_POST['prime'];
$email = $_POST['email'];


    //register the user 
    $queryvote = mysql_query("INSERT INTO vote VALUES ('','$name','1','$q1','$q2','$q3','$email')");
```

I can succesfully echo out the users name by using `$me['name'];`, so I'm struggling to see why I cannot carry it through to my mysql_query. I've even tried populating it into a readonly field in the form, and inserting that value... again though, it never shows in the database.

I know the code I'm using is depreciated, but its needed for this project. Probably a silly error, but we all miss things!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked that $me is accessible after the submit? Perhaps post it along with the other data

Comment: echo the query before you run it to see what it is

Comment: Or what @WizKid said. I always echo the query first before changing it to an insert to make sure it's 100% expected values.

Comment: As a first step in debugging, as WizKid said, build the query as a string,  `$sqltext = "INSERT ... '" . mysql_real_escape_string($q3) . "')";`, then `echo $sqltext;` (or vardump or printf), and then execute the query. This will show whether the problem is in building the SQL text, or its a problem processing the statement. Note: To reduce SQL Injection vulnerabilities, use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: It's a point to note mysql functions are deprecated in the latest php version. Have a look at the new mysqli functions.